# Strange but working ecmascript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I saw this code:

```
const boxTarget = {
  drop({
    allowedDropEffect
  }) {
    return {
      name: `${allowedDropEffect} Dustbin`,
      allowedDropEffect,
    }
  },
}
```

It seems drop is a function and its parameter `{ allowedDropEffect }` will be an object? a class? how drop could be used?

Comment: This is parameter destructuring, it's pulling out the property `allowedDropEffect` from the implied passed in object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an attribute of the passed param called `allowedDropEffect` this syntax is also called *Destructuring assignment*.

```js
const boxTarget = {
   drop({ allowedDropEffect }) {
     return {
        name: `${allowedDropEffect} Dustbin`,
        allowedDropEffect
     }
   }
}

console.log(boxTarget.drop({allowedDropEffect: "Ele", country: "Venezuela"}));
//                                                        ^
//                                                        |
//                                                        +---- This key will be skipped.
```

## Links

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 6):

For cases like this, when you don't know what this piece of ES6 does, it might be useful to ["dumb down"](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBARiAHgFQIYCcDmBTWBeGAbwCgYzyKATdEABwApCZUAbFkAd20oBEbaAogDMh2YLAC-ASiKkKFdLgCu6MLPkbNYVAFtsALhgADACSFW7Lr37DR4iTB5LocAJZgjAGjmbfzNpzcfHS2YlDefjASPvISEVFAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) the new syntax to an older one. This is what this destructuring assignment could be written as:

```
var boxTarget = {
  drop: function drop(_ref) {
    var allowedDropEffect = _ref.allowedDropEffect;

    return {
      name: allowedDropEffect + " Dustbin",
      allowedDropEffect: allowedDropEffect
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: That's it, didn't see it, sorry.